# How to integrate R shiny into current application

Tags: r, shiny

I am wondering if one can integrate R shiny into the current website (PHP or RoR). I just want to leverage the power of R Shiny to make an app embedded into the current website. But as far as I know Shiny needs to run on its own server instead of Apache. Is it possible for a seamless integration without using iframe?

Thanks

Comment: You could use Shiny Server as a proxy behind Apache or Nginx. In other words, you might have *hhttp://your_application/shinyapp/* be proxied to your Shiny Server but have all other URLs served up another way.

Comment: @agstudy Thanks for your reply. Would you please also point me to some document/tutorial how to set up proxy behind Apache? Thanks!

Comment: @zsljulius: I have nginx + shiny. Shiny works on the 3838 port. I use `proxy_pass` and `proxy_redirect` inside `/` location. Then you can form a shiny app with site style.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An alternative is to use an iframe (HTML), as is described here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/shiny-discuss/2VwEWXYJwYs

An example is shown here: http://stla.overblog.com/reactive-3d-surface

Hope this helps

Comment: In short, if you already have your Shiny app up on a server, all you need to do is add it's URL to this line to your HTML document: `<iframe src="your_URL" style="border: none; width: 440px; height: 500px"></iframe>`

Comment: OP asks for a solution without iframe