# Choosing right tool for visualization

Tags: r, d3.js, data-visualization

We are planing to do some visualization for our existing data its a political and news domain.
  After doing my initial research I came to conclusion for using R and D3.

My requirement is the tool should be able to give dynamically, since it is web based visualization (Visualization should be able to change upon change in value)

I have following questions and need help in those.

Is there any other tool which I can use.
R can be use for dynamic visuals? (My application is in php, python based solution can also be ok)

Answer (score 2):

Then you'd need to look into `Rook`, [How to set up an R based service on a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9174114/how-to-set-up-an-r-based-service-on-a-web-page/9174811#9174811), or (better) `Shiny`, [How to integrate R shiny into current application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15592144/how-to-integrate-r-shiny-into-current-application).

Answer (score 0):

If your application (or some parts) is already in python you can use [rpy2](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2_documentation.html) as a bridge between `R` and `python`.